# Using a Shared Module in an Unpacked Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We're developing a basic chrome extension to facilitate increased mobility across accounts representing fragmented web identities.

We can't seem to figure out how to successfully import a Shared Module into an Unpacked Extension.

The official documentation for [Shared Modules](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/shared_modules) seems to imply that it can be done:

> During development, you will need to manually install any Shared Modules your extension uses. Automatic installs do not happen for extensions that are side-loaded or loaded as unpacked extensions. For locally installed, unpacked Shared Modules, you must use the key field to ensure the Shared Modules use the correct IDs.

But we can't figure out how to use the "key" field in this case. Do we need to reference the Shared Module's key in the manifest of the Importing Extension? In our latest (failed) attempt at this, we generated a key by packing the Shared Module, and then tried to reference it like so in the Importing Extension's manifest:

```
"import": [
  {"id": "fdiiokbdnfolebkgnafemkmngiajnhkl",
    "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAv4CmT58yrpUaMt9mr/kqttSR/RFfWUqUung5A2pmuV8ULjh6jBwqYjT1sCQAAYLvrREaGpxrnl2kXYdi+0BvzUg/I56YKURkvAroXNxSaG3ikpNeg9F1tiZ2Ni5IS2ZYhTFSWWGNTkb5RxnduCKuBl1X85kZM8kMFn2J9UytN9iUTEVi44DT9tRGRrZf9VkfpbQ1rlM3AMweNeh16WCdLYe9IexrOKwT0wn33p5UvmBHha6C5GRzED4r17OEl8dHuZzRxrAKzVnUzQ7edqC18oRtyxxNYUetrmqSMbSf654tFOlFdl93JK9pJAg2Xm7T76pgtiExw6iDtSMZyyVI6wIDAQAB"
  }
]
```

Do we need to generate keys for both extensions? Or are we just getting our JSON wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, been searching around for some time but can't seem to find any information on this particular issue.

Comment: You need to specify the `key` field of the manifest to ensure the `id` of your extensions do not change. You don't put them in `import`.

Comment: So you mean the `key` fields have to be defined in both extensions, the Importing Extension and the Exporting Extension? Can we do this simply by defining an arbitrary key value, or do we have to pack both extensions and pick out the automatically generated key values for both?

Comment: At the very minimum, you need to specify a key for the unpacked shared module because the importing extension needs to reference its `id`. You can get a key by packing it and unpacking the `.ctx` file as a zip file.